# Element Doesn't Stay At The Top. Float issue?

Tags: html, css

On this page: http://greengoosemarketing.com/index2.html, the login on the right should sit at the top of the screen, but instead is showing up near the bottom. I would assume it to be a CSS issue. Something to do with the float: left or display: inline-block perhaps?

CSS: http://greengoosemarketing.com/style2.css

Any help would be great!

Comment: Always post the relevant markup **in the question itself**, don't just link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question People shouldn't have to follow links to help you, not even to sites they know (like jsFiddle or jsbin), much less to some random site they've never heard of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the parent div has a fixed width (which it appears to)

```
#rightColumn{
    float: right;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extend the #rightColumn selector in your CSS to look like this:

```
#rightColumn {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: right;
}
```